HashMap Key and Values, does i need to define equals and hashCode() all time?
I have a question about HashMap<Key,Values>.
Let's imagine this scenario:
I have a Person class:
 Person a=new Person(int id, String fullName, int age)

I didn't define the equals and hashCode on this class.
Let's suppose I want to store 10 Person in a HashMap defined as:
 Map<Integer,Person> hashMap=new HashMap<Integer,Person>();

So I will take the number of the persons from the database and then I do a for loop:
 String name="test"; int age="20";

 for(int i=size;i<size+10;i++)
 {
      hashMap.put(Integer.valuesOf(i), new Person(i,name+"i",age++));
 }

The hashMap I think will use hashCode() of the Integer class and I will get a unique hash which will be stored in the hashMap along with the Person objects.
If I'm sure that this hash will be unique I don't need to define the hashCode and equals on the object, no? or at least I need just to define the equals in order to compare between two person in the future.
Am I wrong?

As of Integer, equals and hashcode are purely based on the int value, so no worry. The return value of hashcode is even the int value itself for the Integer class.

For the keys in a HashMap you need equals() (and a hashCode() method does is consistent with equals() - that means for two keys a and b if a.equals(b) is true then they must have the same hashcode, but if a.equals(b) their hashcodes should be different). For the values no such requirements regarding equals() and hashCode() exists.

The key of a HashMap needs to implement consistent hashCode and equals. Note that a hashCode does not have to be unique, but the closer it is to it, the better performance you'll get. java.lang.Integer already implements both of these.
The value of a HashMap doesn't have to implement anything, although having an equals method will help if you want to use containsValue.

Thank you for your response, so in a real world program, i should create another class to manipulate the keys of just the Person class, isn't it?

@elmoutawakil right now, the Person is your value.  It could be a sensible key if you want to have a mapping from a person to some data associated with them (e.g., Map<Person, List<Pet>>), but it really all depends on your programs needs. Of course, if you decide to use Person as a key, you'll need to make sure you implement equals and hashCode for it.

Thank you a lot sir for your answer, please a last one:
when i store Key and Values <Person,Person> , if i understand i store the reference in the hashmap bucket, so there wouldn't be a memory unused? I say that because all what matters for a key is hashCode() and equals()

@elmoutawakil sorry, I don't understand that question. Can you clarify?

ah sorry, i wanted just to say, that hashMap store the reference of objects so adding Person as a value and also as a key (double affectation) will not cause more memory usage isn't it?

Instead of storing  Map<Person,Person> you should use a Set instead.

@elmoutawakil It won't duplicate the space (think of it as two references to the same object, but as JustanotherJavaprogrammer said, if you're mapping from a Person to the same instance of a Person, it's just a really clunky way of having a Set.
